# Python: I have a dual key list, which is the most effective storage object for retreival

Tags: python

I'm working with two hierarchical datasets that contain a complex relation (I'm not using SQL) and they don't share their primary look-up keys. We use this process to keep the two datasets syncronized.

Each dataset is currently stored as a dictionary with the dataset's key as the dictionary's key. After the complex relation is determined I store the other dataset's key as an attribute in the other. This has created the need to create some odd looking helper functions to then follow some of the parent-child relationships.

I was wondering if there might be a more-effective or faster method to this madness as i currently have to pass both datasets to processing functions that need to parse relationships.

examples:

```
leftdataset = {'10000': { 'key': '10000', 'fkey':'asdf', 'parent':'10001'},
               '10001': { 'key': '10001', 'fkey':'qwer', 'parent':''},}
rightdataset= {'asdf': { 'key': 'asdf', 'fkey':'10000', 'parent':'qwer'},
               'qwer': { 'key': 'qwer', 'fkey':'10001', 'parent':''},
```

In order to find the parent's `fkey` I need to:

```
fkey = dataset[dataset['10000']['parent']]['fkey']
```

I was toying around with the idea of presenting a tuple of the key pairs and then looking for the key i need in it such as:

```
keys = [('10000', 'asdf'), ('10001', 'qwer')]

def find_key(key, keyset):
  for keypair in keys:
    if key in keypair:
      k1, k2 = keypair
      if k1 == key:
        return k2
      else:
        return k1
```

But this sounds even less efficient than what I'm doing now. Am I just beating down the wrong path?

Comment: Random lookup in a dictionary will be much more efficient than random lookup in a list, unless you can organize things by an index. I would just encapsulate both datasets into a class and hide the messiness there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this usage appealing to you?

Easy look-up and usage of single entries:

```
>>> left("10000")
Entry({'parent': '10001', 'key': '10000', 'fkey': 'asdf'})
>>> left("10000")['key']
'10000'
>>> left("10000")['parent']
'10001'
```

Easy look-up of parents:

```
>>> left("10000").parent()
Entry({'parent': '', 'key': '10001', 'fkey': 'qwer'})
>>> left("10000").parent().parent()
>>> left("10001")
Entry({'parent': '', 'key': '10001', 'fkey': 'qwer'})
>>> left("10001") is left("10000").parent()
True
```

Easy look-up of related entries:

```
>>> left("10001").related()
Entry({'parent': '', 'key': 'qwer', 'fkey': '10001'})
>>> right("qwer")
Entry({'parent': '', 'key': 'qwer', 'fkey': '10001'})
>>> right(left("10001").related()['key'])
Entry({'parent': '', 'key': 'qwer', 'fkey': '10001'})
>>> right("qwer") is left("10001").related()
True
```

Particularly here is the example in your question: parent's foreign key:

```
>>> left("10000").parent()['fkey']
'qwer'
```

If so, then here is the code! Classes:

```
class Entry(object):
    def __init__(self, dataset, d):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.d = d

    def parent(self):
        return self.dataset.parent_of(self)
    def related(self):
        if not self.dataset.related_dataset:
            raise ValueError("no related dataset specified")
        return self.dataset.related_dataset(self['fkey'])

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.d.__getitem__(k)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Entry(%s)" % repr(self.d)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.d)

class Dataset(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = dict((k, Entry(self, v)) for (k,v) in data.items())
        self.related_dataset = None

    def set_related_dataset(self, dataset):
        self.related_dataset = dataset

    def entry(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, Entry): return key
        return self.data[key]
    def __call__(self, key):
        return self.entry(key)

    def parent_of(self, entry):
        entry = self.entry(entry)

        if not entry['parent']:
            return None
        return self.data[entry['parent']]
```

And the usage for the data you've provided:

```
leftdata = {'10000': { 'key': '10000', 'fkey':'asdf', 'parent':'10001'},
               '10001': { 'key': '10001', 'fkey':'qwer', 'parent':''},}
rightdata = {'asdf': { 'key': 'asdf', 'fkey':'10000', 'parent':'qwer'},
               'qwer': { 'key': 'qwer', 'fkey':'10001', 'parent':''}}

left = Dataset(leftdata)
right = Dataset(rightdata)
left.set_related_dataset(right)
right.set_related_dataset(left)
```

Explanation: Wrap each dict value in an `Entry` class with `__getitem__` defined to make it usable as a dict (more or less). Have a `Dataset` class that maps primary keys to these `Entry`s. Provide the `Entry` access to this dataset and provide convenient methods `.parent()` and `.related()`. In order for `.related()` to work, set which dataset the "related" one should be with `set_related_dataset` and it all ties together.

Now you can even just pass `Entry`s and you'll be able to access the related entries without needing to pass both datasets in.

Comment: Hmm. left('10000').parent().related() kinda sexy. I'll look at this more

Answer (score 2):

Based off of Mark Ransom's comment, maybe you can organize a class like this:

```
class Storage(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self._leftdataset = {
            '10000': { 'key': '10000', 'fkey':'asdf', 'parent':'10001'},
            '10001': { 'key': '10001', 'fkey':'qwer', 'parent':''}
        }

        self._rightdataset= {
            'asdf': { 'key': 'asdf', 'fkey':'10000', 'parent':'qwer'},
            'qwer': { 'key': 'qwer', 'fkey':'10001', 'parent':''}
        }

    def get(self, key):
        d1 = self._leftdataset
        d2 = self._rightdataset

        if key in d1:
            left = d1[key]
            right = d2[left['fkey']]
        else:
            right = d2[key]
            left = d1[right['fkey']]

        return left, right
```

And use a single lookup method:

```
s = Storage()

s.get('10000')
# ({'fkey': 'asdf', 'key': '10000', 'parent': '10001'},
#  {'fkey': '10000', 'key': 'asdf', 'parent': 'qwer'})


s.get('qwer')
# ({'fkey': 'qwer', 'key': '10001', 'parent': ''},
#  {'fkey': '10001', 'key': 'qwer', 'parent': ''})
```